# Timeouts in java.net.http.HttpClient not working as expected

Tags: java

Java Http client with 100ms timeout throws Timeout exception when connecting to an API.

1. I have verified that api responds within 10ms with a curl call.

   `curl --max-time 0.01 http://localhost:8000/`

```
    @Test
    public void testHTTPClient() throws URISyntaxException, IOException, InterruptedException {


        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build().newHttpClient();
        java.net.URI uri = new URI("http://localhost:8000/");
        HttpRequest req = HttpRequest.newBuilder(uri).GET().timeout(Duration.ofMillis(100)).build();
        long start = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
        try {
            java.net.http.HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(req, java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            System.out.println(response.body());
        } catch (HttpTimeoutException e) {
            System.out.println("Time taken " + (Instant.now().toEpochMilli() - start));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I am expecting the output printed to the screen. But I get the following exception.

```
Time taken 159

java.net.http.HttpTimeoutException: request timed out
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:559)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:119)
```

When I run the test multiple times with the 100ms timeout. Few instances have a successful response. With a larger timeout like 150ms, I haven't faced the timeout exception.

Comment: If you set it higher, does it eventually start working?

Comment: Updated the question. Please take a look.

Comment: Does it timeout after 100ms (i.e. does the connection just take longer with Java than with curl), or does it timeout sooner (i.e. is the connection speed the same, but the timeout parameter you provide is misinterpreted)? Two very distinct underlying issues that'd be good to narrow down.

Comment: `HttpClient` might be doing other things like managing threads, so I wouldn't expect it to perform as good as curl.

Comment: @MaxVollmer I have updated the question. It looks to me that the timeout is interpreted correctly but java client is taking time.

Comment: @Kartik Agree performance could be different. But I think 90 ms difference is too much. Can you point me to any documentation which states how much buffer we need to add to timeout?